# How can I get the 12th node aligned and size the rest properly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

I am experimenting with the `graphdrawing` library from tikz and produced this graph:

[image]

How can I align the node 12 such that it is one the same height with node 10?
And also, why are nodes 10,11,12 bigger than the rest? I would prefer them to have the same radii.

My MWE for the picture above (needs to be compiled with LuaTeX):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular,layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [simple necklace layout,node distance = 1cm, nodes={circle,draw},layered layout,horizontal= 1 to 3]
{
        1->2->3->1;
        3--4;
        4->5->6->4;
        6--7;
        7->8->9->7;
        9--10;
        10->11->12->10;
        12--[bend right]11;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I align the node 12 such that it is one the same height with
> node 10?

Since the node distance is `1cm` simply move the node down with the `nudge down` node option. Below I used `5mm`.

> And also, why are nodes 10,11,12 bigger than the rest? I would prefer
> them to have the same radii.

Use the `minimum width` node option. Below I used `1cm`.

[image]

You can find more features on Section *Fine-Tuning Positions of Nodes* of the TikZ documentation.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular,layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[
    simple necklace layout,
    node distance = 1cm,
    nodes={circle,draw,minimum width=1cm}, % <-- added here
    layered layout,
    horizontal=1 to 3
  ]
  {
    1->2->3->1;
    3--4;
    4->5->6->4;
    6--7;
    7->8->9->7;
    9--10;
    10->11->12[nudge down=5mm]->10;  % <-- added here
    12--[bend right]11;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you for your effort and reference :)